# AIR iOS app fails to install, error message: "A signed resource has been added, modified, or deleted."

Tags: flash, air, fdt

I'm making an iOS app using AIR 3.1 and Flex 4.5.1, and if I package it using -target ipa-test-interpreter the ipa file installs with no problem, it just runs kind of slow.  If I use -target ipa-debug or -ipa-ad-hoc then the install fails with the error message "A signed resource has been added, modified, or deleted."  Nothing else has changed

Has anyone run into this before or have any idea what's causing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick search of the web and it looks like there's no 100% sure solution why it does this.

[This guy here says he found a solution](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4198727?tstart=0) - it was with the iPhone Configuration Utility.

Other than that, I would suggest trying the latest AIR SDK. It could be issues with you using an older AIR SDK and targeting a newer iOS.

Comment: I'm using Windows 7 and the iPhone Configuration Utility, so that must be the problem. I can't sync to this iPad with iTunes, but I was able to get it installed using a Mac.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! Helped me from breaking my iPad lol.